# How to render children within react functional components using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to render the component that is passed to the react functional component using react and typescript.

below is my code,

```
function MainComponent () {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <SomeOtheComponent/>
            <DragAndDrop>
                <ListContent> //this is the children for the DragAndDrop component and want this to 
                    //render within DragAndDrop component
                    {condition_true && (
                        <FirstList/>
                    )}
                    {condition_true && (
                        <SecondList/>
                    )}
                </ListContent>
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }




const DragAndDrop: React.FC = ({ children }) => { //here i am passing children
    const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
    const [dragCounter, setDragCounter] = useState(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // componentDidMount()
        setDragCounter(0);
    }, []);

    const handleDrag = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    };

    const handleDragIn = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        setDragCounter((prev: number) => prev + 1);
        if (e.dataTransfer.files) {
            setDragging(true);
        }

     };

     const handleDragOut = (e: any) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         setDragCounter((prev: number) => prev - 1);
         if (dragCounter === 0) {
             setDragging(false);
         }
     }; 

     const handleDrop = (e: any) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         setDragging(false);
         if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
             e.dataTransfer.clearData();
             setDragCounter(0);
         }
     };

     return (
         <DropZone
             ref={dropRef}
             onDragEnter={handleDragIn}
             onDragLeave={handleDragOut}
             onDragOver={handleDrag}
             onDrop={handleDrop}
         >
             {dragging && <DropZoneOverlay>{children}</DropZoneOverlay>}
         </DropZone>
     );
 };
```

Now the question is why doesnt ListContent within DragAndDrop Component render....I am not sure if there is something wrong with the way i pass children to DragAndDrop component in MainComponent. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dragging` value is set to `false` from the `useState` call in `DragAndDrop`, so on first render, the `DropZoneOverlay` won't get rendered.

```
{dragging && <DropZoneOverlay>{children}</DropZoneOverlay>}
```